# #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Wamp Server

Tags: php, android, mysql, wamp

I'm trying to connect Android with PHP, MySQL, for that I'm referring [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). I installed WAMP server successfully on my local machine and now I want login to phpmyadmin by entering "http://localhost/phpmyadmin" url in my browser but I'm getting following error-

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

For more information, please see the below screenshot-

[image]

One more thing I would like to mention here is, after starting Wamp server it shows the icon in Orange colour. I googled n tried almost all available solutions but unable to resolve my issue yet. The strange thing is yesterday it was working successfully but in today morning when I tried to login again I'm getting this error. Please help me to resolve this issue also let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually started the mysql daemon?

Comment: Smells like your MySQL/MariaDB server isn't running. Kan you confirm it *is* running with task manager?

Comment: @DaanMeijer I started WAMP server and it is running in task manager but showing icon in Orange colour (it should be green)

Comment: Do you have a MySQL process running as well?

Comment: @DaanMeijer NO. Task Manager not showing MySQL Process running.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.

Comment: @DaanMeijer Can u plz help me how can I solve this problem.?

Comment: Sorry, not enough experience with WAMP. Can't help you with this one.

Comment: @DaanMeijer Anyway, thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 3):

> Case 1 :

One is mysql port not conflict with other application

> Case 2 :

Second one is some mysql table We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.

> Case 1 : solution

You could go to `wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.x /`
There can find `my.config` file you can change below mention port number what we change like that.
The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients

```
[client]
password = your_password
port = 3309
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
and
The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
```

As well as you could change php/bin/ folder
Php.ini here you could change port number default one 3306 to 3309 like this
port = 3309
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

> Case 2 Solution :

`Wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.xx/data`
Here can find the data folder in that your project name appeared open that project and then find the `currepted (uses space ID: 43 at filepath: .\myschool\tbl_student.ibd`

`InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\myschool\tbl_student.ibd)` file then delete it .
`wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\myschool`
here you find the table struce then delete currepted table structure like this extension tbl_student.ibd
Logs file you can find wamp/logs folder here you can select MySQL then go down see what the error then you can resolve it .

Courtesy [webTutorialsPoint.com](http://www.webtutorialspoint.com/php/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/) and [ApacheForum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,87426)

Answer (score 1):

have you configure control panel of your server .. 
i had same problem then i found it was nothing wrong there

the problem was the other application was using the same port which control panel of my server was trying to access

hope you will find your error ..

good luck

Answer (score 0):

That's Because mysqld is not running Check it mysqld On \MySQL\bin

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wamp go to     `~\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin{version}` and open `config.inc.php` then add `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '????'` bellow `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'` in `/* Server parameters */` section.

replace `????` with your current port (3306 is default port so if you change the port, write it here)